# How to filter steady state results from JTL file in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to filter jmeter log file (.JTL) to seperate ramp up and steady state statistics. I have been doing it by editing the log file in notepad / excel. Can anyone suggest if there is any automated way or plug in to do this? Doing this manually takes lot of time. Please help!

Comment: Sorry, but it's irrelevant to my question

Answer (score 0):

There is [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) plugin which has `--start-offset` and `--end-offset` parameters so given you know the duration of ramp-up you can easily filter these out like:

```
FilterResults.bat --output-file steady.csv --input-file your-results-file.jtl --start-offset 2 --end-offset 180
```

Filter Results Tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

[image]